# Efficiently use vector registers

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, vectorization

I am considering to vectorize an application on Xeon Phi. The calculation part of the program looks like this (only a part of the code):

```
            t[0] = (c[0]+c[16]+ c[32]) + (c[4]+c[20]+c[36]) +(c[8]+c[24]+c[40]);
            t[1] = (c[1]+c[17]+ c[33]) + (c[5]+c[21]+c[37]) +(c[9]+c[25]+c[41]);
            t[2] = (c[2]+c[18]+ c[34]) + (c[6]+c[22]+c[38]) +(c[10]+c[26]+c[42]);
            t[3] = (c[3]+c[19]+ c[35]) + (c[7]+c[23]+c[39]) +(c[11]+c[27]+c[43]);

            t[4] = (c[4]+c[20]+ c[36]) - (c[8]+c[24]+c[40]) -(c[12]+c[28]+c[44]);
            t[5] = (c[5]+c[21]+ c[37]) - (c[9]+c[25]+c[41]) -(c[13]+c[29]+c[45]);
            t[6] = (c[6]+c[22]+ c[38]) - (c[10]+c[26]+c[42]) -(c[14]+c[30]+c[46]);
            t[7] = (c[7]+c[23]+ c[39]) - (c[11]+c[27]+c[43]) -(c[15]+c[31]+c[47]);

            t[8] = (c[16]-c[32]- c[48]) + (c[20]-c[36]-c[52]) +(c[24]-c[40]-c[56]);
            t[9] = (c[17]-c[33]- c[49]) + (c[21]-c[37]-c[53]) +(c[25]-c[41]-c[57]);
            t[10] = (c[18]-c[34]- c[50]) + (c[22]-c[38]-c[54]) +(c[26]-c[42]-c[58]);
            t[11] = (c[19]-c[35]- c[51]) + (c[23]-c[39]-c[55]) +(c[27]-c[43]-c[59]);
```

It loads data to an array c and then adds or substracts the elements in c; at last stores data in the array t. The length of c is 64. The problem is that in Xeon Phi, there is only 32 vector registers, so I can not put all the 64 elements of c in 32 vector registers. I need to load a part of data then calculate the results, then load some again. I may need to load some data several times in order to finsh the whole calculation. I notice that in the code, some intermediate data can be used several times. The whole procedure is like a tree.

So the question is that is there any algorithm that can efficiently decide when to load data, perform computation and store the intermediate data?

Comment: The data is float, and for each element of c, like c[0], it includes 16 floats. I should point that the data type of each element in c and t is __m512.